# signed char to 0x80 cause truncation of constant value

Tags: c++

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    signed char min = -128;  //line1
    signed char min2 = 0x80; //line2
}
```

line1, ok
line2, warning C4309 'conversion' : truncation of constant value

VS2010, -WX -W4

0x80 is same as -128, what's wrong ?

Comment: This attempts to perform numerical conversion, _not_ bitwise. Anyway, even if it did, you shouldn't rely on assumptions about bit representation, which are inherently non-portable.

Comment: Where do you get anything to do with bits in this question, @underscore_d? You just have two different ways of representing a numerical constant: decimal and hexadecimal.

Comment: @CodyGray `0x80` is `0b10000000`, which encodes `-128` in 8-bit two's complement. I assumed the OP thought they could exploit this happenstance. Either way, it's worth cautioning against. Again, the program will attempt to convert to the destination type using the numerical value of the source, not its bit representation.

Comment: ...and hex is unsigned, so `0x80` is **+** 128, with the bitwise similarity to 8-bit two's complement -128 being an irrelevant coincidence as far as the Standard is concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *not* the same: `0x80` is 128, not -128.

It is likely to be *converted* to -128 in the initialization, although the standard does not guarantee this:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined

Answer (score 1):

`signed char` has a range of -128 to 127 (both inclusive). You are assigning 128 (0x80) to it. Thus truncating it, since it is out-of-range.